# Syntax error 1064 in CREATE TABLE statement

Tags: mysql

This is the MySQL code I have so far:

```
CREATE TABLE /*TABLE_PREFIX*/t_buttons (
    fk_i_item_id INT NULL,
    fk_i_user_id INT NULL,
    b_email varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    b_type ENUM('buynow','addtocart','subscribe','donate') DEFAULT NULL,
    b_style  ENUM 

('default','round','frame') DEFAULT NULL,
  b_target ENUM('_self','_blank') DEFAULT NULL,
  b_text varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  b_tooltip varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  b_shipping int(11) NOT NULL,
  b_a3 int(10) NOT NULL,
  b_p3 int(10) NOT NULL,
  b_t3 varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  b_a1 int(11) NOT NULL,
  b_p1 int(11) NOT NULL,
  b_t1 varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  b_cpp_logo_image varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  b_return varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  b_lc varchar(10) NOT NULL,

      PRIMARY KEY (fk_i_item_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Running this code in MySQL on the command line gives me this error:

> ERROR 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax 'CREATE TABLE
>   oc_t_buttons ( fk_i_item_id INT NULL, fk_i_user' at line 1

Comment: Works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/21158

Comment: your create table syntax is correct but table name will be t_buttons till you don't pass its prefix as i think oc....so may be you are not passing prefix correctly..first check just table name t_buttons if you are able to create table then you can check your issue with passing prefix with table name.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the error you posted and the script which you have shown are different. The error you posted as

```
CREATE TABLE oc_t_buttons (
```

whereas the actual script which you have pasted is

```
CREATE TABLE /*TABLE_PREFIX*/t_buttons (
```

which works fine. Here is a demo **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/21158)**

Even if the script is changed as

```
CREATE TABLE oc_t_buttons (
```

then also it is working fine. See the **[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/714f3)**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like wrong definition... Your error is for "oc_t_buttons"?

Answer (score 0):

You use

```
fk_i_item_id INT NULL
```

and at the last line:

```
PRIMARY KEY (fk_i_item_id)
```

`PRIMARY key` can not allow `NULL` values.
You can change it to be:

```
`fk_i_item_id` int(11) NOT NULL Default '0'
```

Or

```
`fk_i_item_id` int(11) NOT NULL Auto_Increment
```